# upload preview image in xmpp

Tags: javascript, xmpp

I'm working on chat web application using xmpp and angular what i want is to know is how to preview an image before the file is actually downloaded I read the documentation in here https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0231.html
and here
https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0363.html

but still i didn't understand how to implement it.
I convert the image to base64 and i need to know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0231.html that is a base64 image of the thumbnail.
We were doing this before. But unfortunately, since sending/attaching a base64 image to an xml, this will actually make the size larger than the binary. So what we did was we created a different microservice that will handle all media types, and we will only pass the secret_key and access_key of that image inside the XMPPMessage payload. In this way, we will use that access_key and secret_key to retrieve that Thumbnail and image or other media from different api/server.